# Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, jdbc, classpath

I started using JDBC so I went to Classpath, changed it to classpath of OracleDriver and program compiled. There was classpath set earlier there which I did not bother to check.Now, the program can compile but I am not able to run it.This is the error message I am getting:

```
Could not find or load main class 'classname that I am trying to run'
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: how do you run it ? what does your classlook like

Comment: I run it using command prompt.I wrote program in Notepad and saved it to desktop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you compile, there are generated `.class` files that get made from the `.java` files.

When you want to run, you need the generated `.class` files on the path, so find the directory where they live, and add that directory to the class path.

Note that if you define a class as

```
package com.corp.myproduct;

public class Sifter {
}
```

It will generate to a path of

```
<root>/com/corp/myproduct/Sifter.class
```

or on windows

```
<root>\com\corp\myproduct\Sifter.class
```

where root is the "top level directory" of the compiled output.  You don't add `<root>/com/corp/myproduct/` in such a case to the classpath, you just add `<root>`.

Comment: my .class files are created exactly where I save my program

Comment: @Simrankaur And I will bet that you don't have the root of that directory tree on your classpath.  Just because it is in the same place as the source files doesn't mean that it will be on the classpath.